# Function to find substring in a list of strings and add them to the resulting list

Tags: javascript, strings, sorting, react.js, typescript

I am trying to look for a substring in a list of strings. My end result is an array that contains the presence of substring first based on `course.name` and then based on `course.description`. Is there a better way to write the following code?

Firstly, I am looking for the substring in the `course.name` field using the `indexOf` method and adding it to the `foundCourseList` array.

```
let uniqueIds: string[] = [];
let foundCourseList: CourseItem[] = [];
this.props.courses.forEach((course: CourseItem) => {
    let courseNameListTobeSearchedIn = course.name.split(" ");
    
    courseNameListTobeSearchedIn.forEach((word: string) => {
        this.state.inputWord.split(" ").forEach((inputWord: string) => {
            if (word.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputWord.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && !uniqueIds.includes(course.id)) {
                foundCourseList.push(course);
                uniqueIds.push(course.id);
            };
        });
    });
});
```

Then I am looking for the same substring in the `course.description` field using the `indexOf` method and add it to the `foundCourseList` array. In that was the search results display results based on `course.name` followed by the results based on the `course.description`.

```
this.props.courses.forEach((course: CourseItem) => {
    let courseDescriptionTobeSearchedIn: string[];
    course.description && (courseDescriptionTobeSearchedIn = course.description.split(" "));
    
    if (courseDescriptionTobeSearchedIn) {
        courseDescriptionTobeSearchedIn.forEach((word: string) => {
            this.state.inputWord.split(" ").forEach((inputWord: string) => {
                if (word.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputWord.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && !uniqueIds.includes(course.id)) {
                    foundCourseList.push(course);
                    uniqueIds.push(course.id);
                };
            });
        });
    }
});
return foundCourseList;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several inefficient elements in the implementation.

#### Use a `Set` instead of an array for fast lookups

The code uses `uniqueIds` to keep track of the ids seen so far.
The `uniqueIds.includes` does a linear scan over the items in the array.
Using a `Set` would make that constant time.

#### Avoid repeated computations

There are several repeated computations here:

> ```
> this.props.courses.forEach((course: CourseItem) => {
>     let courseNameListTobeSearchedIn = course.name.split(" ");
>     
>     courseNameListTobeSearchedIn.forEach((word: string) => {
>         this.state.inputWord.split(" ").forEach((inputWord: string) => {
>             if (word.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputWord.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && !uniqueIds.includes(course.id)) {
> ```

For each course, for each word in the course name, `this.state.inputWord` is repeatedly split to words, and then lowercased.
Assuming that `this.state.inputWord` doesn't change between iterations,
it would be better to lowercase it and split it to words once,
before `this.props.courses.forEach` begins.

For each input word, each `word` in the course name is repeatedly lowercased.
It would be better to lowercase `course.name` once before splitting it to words.

The last kind of repeated computation is when there are duplicate words in the input or course names.
If that's unrealistic, then it might not be worth to optimize.
(Otherwise, you could use `Set` to remove duplicates.)

#### Putting it together

With the above ideas applied, the code becomes:

```
const uniqueIds: Set<string> = new Set();

const inputWords = this.state.inputWord
    .toLowerCase()
    .split(" ");

this.props.courses.forEach((course: CourseItem) => {
    course.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .forEach((word: string) => {
            inputWords.forEach((inputWord: string) => {
                if (!uniqueIds.has(course.id) && word.indexOf(inputWord) >= 0) {
                    foundCourseList.push(course);
                    uniqueIds.add(course.id);
                };
            });
        });
});
```

Notice that I switched the evaluation order in the conditions here:

> ```
> if (!uniqueIds.has(course.id) && word.indexOf(inputWord) >= 0) {
> ```

The reason to order this way is because `!uniqueIds.has(course.id)` is the fast operation (thanks to making `uniqueIds` a `Set`), and `word.indexOf(inputWord)` is slower.
This way, if the fast condition doesn't pass,
the slower one can be skipped,
so the ordering is significant.

#### Searching in both `course.name` and `course.description`

The same points I demonstrated above on the snippet searching in `course.name` apply equally to searching in `course.description` too.

Currently the search results based on `course.name` and the search results based on `course.description` both end up in the common array `foundCourseList`.
As such it seems to make sense to combine the words from `course.name` and `course.description` into set to make sure you don't loop over the same word twice,
and in this case a single loop over the combined keywords will suffice:

```
courses.forEach((course: CourseItem) => {
    const keywords: Set<string> = new Set();

    course.name
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .forEach(keywords.add, keywords);

    course.description
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .forEach(keywords.add, keywords);

    keywords
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")
        .forEach((word: string) => {
            inputWords.forEach((inputWord: string) => {
                if (!uniqueIds.has(course.id) && word.indexOf(inputWord) >= 0) {
                    foundCourseList.push(course);
                    uniqueIds.add(course.id);
                };
            });
        });
});
```

#### Going even further

If the frequency of search operations is significantly higher than the frequency of changes to the underlying fields (name and description),
then you may want to optimize further,
to avoid recomputing the keywords over and over again to the same set of words.

For example you could add a `keywords` property and recompute it every time `name` or `description` changes,
instead of recomputing it on every search.
This optimization is not free,
because it requires more memory to store the keywords,
and more computation when `name` or `description` changes.
It depends on your use case if this trade-off makes sense or not.

Finally, you could speed up the search even further by building a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) from the keywords instead of a simple `Set`.
This will cost even more memory, another trade-off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its helpful to achieve a faster operation. However this did not address my problem where I am running the loop twice for searching for the input keyword in 2 arraylists: course.name and course.description.
How can I run the loop just once to look for the input word in 2 arraylists course.name and course.description and add it to the foundCourseList array?

Comment: @user2140740 I added one more section now specifically for that point. (And then one more section with further improvement ideas.)

Comment: thanks for the improvement, however this code is missing sorting of the required results and I have just implemented it in the below solution

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally formulated the code such that it sorts the results firstly based on course.name and secondly based on course.description.

```
let foundCourseListName: CourseItem[] = [];
let foundCourseListDesc: CourseItem[] = [];
    const uniqueIds: Set<string> = new Set();   
    const inputWords = this.state.inputWord
                                 .toLowerCase()
                                 .split(" ");
   
    this.props.courses.forEach((course: CourseItem) => {
        course.name.toLowerCase().split(" ")
                   .forEach((word: string) => {
                      inputWords.forEach((inputWord: string) => {
                               if (!uniqueIds.has(course.id) && word.indexOf(inputWord) >= 0) {
                                   foundCourseListName.push(course);
                                   uniqueIds.add(course.id);
                               };
                       });
                   });
       if (course.description) {
          course.description.toLowerCase().split(" ")
                .forEach((word: string) => {
                    inputWords.forEach((inputWord: string) => {
                       if (!uniqueIds.has(course.id) && word.indexOf(inputWord) >= 0) {
                                       foundCourseListDesc.push(course);
                                       uniqueIds.add(course.id);
                                   };
                           });
                       });
                   }
               });
  return foundCourseListName.concat(foundCourseListDesc);
```

Comment: If you are looking for a review of additional code it is better to create a follow up question with a link back to the original question.